# mysql_upgrade failing at Event Scheduler after replacing mySQL 5.7 with MariaDB 10.0

Tags: mysql, upgrade, mariadb

I replaced mySQL 5.7 with MariaDB 10.0 on my Ubuntu 16.04 server. I backed up the databases before installation using mysqldump. During the MariaDB install it said a "flag file" present meant the DBs weren't binary compatible, so I restored the backup post-install. MariaDB doesn't like my privilege tables, so I tried to run mysql_upgrade. This is a log of the output (with full verbosity and system tables only):

```
root@server:~# mysql_upgrade --force -s -vvv
Looking for 'mysql' as: mysql
Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: mysqlcheck
The --upgrade-system-tables option was used, user tables won't be touched.
Phase 1/6: Checking and upgrading mysql database
Running 'mysqlcheck with default connection arguments
# Connecting to localhost...
# Disconnecting from localhost...
Processing databases
mysql
CHECK TABLE `column_stats`  FOR UPGRADE
mysql.column_stats                                 OK
CHECK TABLE `columns_priv`  FOR UPGRADE
mysql.columns_priv                                 OK
CHECK TABLE `db`  FOR UPGRADE
mysql.db                                           OK
CHECK TABLE `engine_cost`  FOR UPGRADE
mysql.engine_cost                                  OK
CHECK TABLE `event`  FOR UPGRADE
mysql.event                                        OK
CHECK TABLE `event_old`  FOR UPGRADE
mysql.event_old                                    OK
CHECK TABLE `func`  FOR UPGRADE
mysql.func                                         OK
CHECK TABLE `gtid_executed`  FOR UPGRADE
mysql.gtid_executed                                OK
CHECK TABLE `gtid_slave_pos`  FOR UPGRADE
mysql.gtid_slave_pos                               OK
CHECK TABLE `help_category`  FOR UPGRADE
mysql.help_category                                OK
CHECK TABLE `help_keyword`  FOR UPGRADE
mysql.help_keyword                                 OK
CHECK TABLE `help_relation`  FOR UPGRADE
mysql.help_relation                                OK
CHECK TABLE `help_topic`  FOR UPGRADE
mysql.help_topic                                   OK
CHECK TABLE `host`  FOR UPGRADE
mysql.host                                         OK
CHECK TABLE `index_stats`  FOR UPGRADE
mysql.index_stats                                  OK
CHECK TABLE `innodb_index_stats`  FOR UPGRADE
mysql.innodb_index_stats                           OK
CHECK TABLE `innodb_table_stats`  FOR UPGRADE
mysql.innodb_table_stats                           OK
CHECK TABLE `ndb_binlog_index`  FOR UPGRADE
mysql.ndb_binlog_index                             OK
CHECK TABLE `plugin`  FOR UPGRADE
mysql.plugin                                       OK
CHECK TABLE `proc`  FOR UPGRADE
mysql.proc                                         OK
CHECK TABLE `procs_priv`  FOR UPGRADE
mysql.procs_priv                                   OK
CHECK TABLE `proxies_priv`  FOR UPGRADE
mysql.proxies_priv                                 OK
CHECK TABLE `roles_mapping`  FOR UPGRADE
mysql.roles_mapping                                OK
CHECK TABLE `server_cost`  FOR UPGRADE
mysql.server_cost                                  OK
CHECK TABLE `servers`  FOR UPGRADE
mysql.servers                                      OK
CHECK TABLE `slave_master_info`  FOR UPGRADE
mysql.slave_master_info                            OK
CHECK TABLE `slave_relay_log_info`  FOR UPGRADE
mysql.slave_relay_log_info                         OK
CHECK TABLE `slave_worker_info`  FOR UPGRADE
mysql.slave_worker_info                            OK
CHECK TABLE `table_stats`  FOR UPGRADE
mysql.table_stats                                  OK
CHECK TABLE `tables_priv`  FOR UPGRADE
mysql.tables_priv                                  OK
CHECK TABLE `time_zone`  FOR UPGRADE
mysql.time_zone                                    OK
CHECK TABLE `time_zone_leap_second`  FOR UPGRADE
mysql.time_zone_leap_second                        OK
CHECK TABLE `time_zone_name`  FOR UPGRADE
mysql.time_zone_name                               OK
CHECK TABLE `time_zone_transition`  FOR UPGRADE
mysql.time_zone_transition                         OK
CHECK TABLE `time_zone_transition_type`  FOR UPGRADE
mysql.time_zone_transition_type                    OK
CHECK TABLE `user`  FOR UPGRADE
mysql.user                                         OK
Phase 2/6: Fixing views... Skipped
Phase 3/6: Running 'mysql_fix_privilege_tables'
ERROR 1408 (HY000) at line 539: Event Scheduler: An error occurred when initializing system tables. Disabling the Event Scheduler.
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
```

How do I resolve the event scheduler issue so that the process can complete? I had to --skip-grant-tables to get to this point so I'm understandably keen to fix this so I can run the server with proper privileges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to resolve this.

I did get to where I wanted to be, though: I started the server with `--skip-grant-tables`, backed up each database I wanted to keep, then removed the data folder and ran `mysql_install_db` to create a fresh copy of the system tables. I set permissions up again, and then re-imported the databases. All OK now.